# Jetpack Compose Navigation: Views Disappearing when Switching Destinations

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

StackOverflow community!

I'm facing an issue with Jetpack Compose navigation using NavHost and rememberNavController. My app works as expected most of the time, but occasionally, when I tap buttons to switch between screens, the content disappears, and only the Surface remains visible.

[image]

[image]

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val navController = rememberNavController()
            NavigationTestTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = Color.Cyan
                ) {
                    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "First") {
                        composable(route = "First") {
                            FirstScreen(onButtonTap = { navController.navigate("Second") })
                        }
                        composable(route = "Second") {
                            SecondScreen(onButtonTap = { navController.popBackStack() })
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun FirstScreen(onButtonTap: () -> Unit) {
    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Blue)
    ) {
        CustomButton(title = "To Second View") {
            onButtonTap()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun SecondScreen(onButtonTap: () -> Unit) {
    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Green)
    ) {
        CustomButton(title = "Pop View") {
            onButtonTap()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun CustomButton(title: String, onClick: () -> Unit) {
    Button(
        onClick = { onClick() },
        modifier = Modifier.size(width = 200.dp, height = 40.dp)
    ) {
        Text(text = title)
    }
}
```

The expected behavior is:

1. Display the FirstScreen on the initial launch.
2. Navigate to the SecondScreen and add it to the back stack when the button in the FirstScreen is tapped.
3. Pop the SecondScreen when the button in the SecondScreen is tapped, and display the FirstScreen again.

However, sometimes when I tap buttons on both FirstScreen and SecondScreen to switch views, the views get removed from the back stack, and only the Surface with the Cyan color remains visible.

[image]

I've tried simplifying the code and isolating the issue, but I can't seem to pinpoint the root cause. Any suggestions or insights into what might be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was I used `popBackStack` to dismiss the current view. Instead, I used [navigateUP](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#navigateUp()), and worked well.